# Use a Variable as the Value for a Limit Expression in Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm writing a Liquid template for Jekyll, and wish to do something like so:

```
{% for example in examples | limit:{{ site.examplelimit}} %}
```

However, this never works. `{{ site.examplelimit}}` returns a value, and even something more precise like preceding the above with:

```
{% capture examplelimitint %}site.examplelimit{% endcapture %}
{% assign examplelimitint = examplelimitint | plus:0 %}
```

...doesn't help.

So, is there really no way to use a variable for the value to limit in Liquid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
{% for example in examples | limit: site.examplelimit %}
```